# Can Nginx resolves upstream server name given as SRV DNS records?

Tags: http, nginx, dns

I just want to know if Nginx is able to resolve SRV DNS records when given as the upstream server address. It seems like it's not the case, but maybe there is a workaround if it can't do this out-of-the-box.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SRV records are not meant to be used like A(ddress) records.
In theory it should be possible to hack nginx to resolve SRV records as well but the only advantage I could see is the 'weight' and 'priority' fields used in SRV records.

You can already use this feature in nginx config:

```
upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com weight=5;
  server backend2.example.com:8080;
  server unix:/tmp/backend3;
}
```

[HttpUpstreamModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule)

Comment: Nginx and Nginx+ does now resolv SRV record. Nginx have severe caveheat (TTL not taken into account for example) that force to use Nginx+ which is the commercial part of Nginx. I know it's a shame. So Nginx will be superseeded by Vulcand if they continue this strange politic. More informations here : https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/

Comment: @jmcollin92 You should post that as an answer. Someone coming to this question might not read the comments and assume it's not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Free nginx does not support SRV records.

`resolve` and `service` keywords for [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream) directive are not available in free nginx.

There are some free solutions available,

- [ngx_upstream_resolveMK](https://github.com/HatsuneMiku3939/ngx_upstream_resolveMK)
- [srv-router](https://github.com/vlipco/srv-router)