# Communications between services in ECS using the bridge network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I am using the bridge network to try and communicate between services. I have the services running independently but am unable to resolve by the `<service_name>.<namespace>`. The SRV records are being created for the services.

Should I be linking the services?

I am using the EC2 for clustering.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944833/5030709) if it helps on understanding on how to implement ECS Service Discover.

Comment: Thanks @Imran, I had already gone through your post and it helped me understand my problem. Both the options you suggested don't inspire much, any other recommendations in terms of using some other 3rd party services to achieve service discovery?

Comment: see if you want to use [consul](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/service-discovery-via-consul-with-amazon-ecs/) service discovery which requires you to make additional changes to ECS EC2 AMI.