# AWS ECS services communicate over service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, service-discovery, ecs-service-connect

I have ECS services in the same cluster, on the same Vpc and subnet. To communicate ECS services with each other I use service discovery, my network model is `awsvpc` and the record type is SRV. I connect a config map to my ECS services where I write the DNS name for my ECS services format like this `SERVICE_NAME.ecs-service-discovery.ecs-namespace.local` but my services cannot communicate.

I try change domain names and give with port like `SERVICE_NAME.ecs-service-discovery.ecs-namespace.local:5000` but it don't work. I have question i need config map where will be write DNS names? And which can be reason that my services can't communicate?

Comment: You need to show how your services are trying to communicate with each other. Show the actual code. And be aware that most things don't support using SRV records out of the box.

Comment: This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897754/not-able-to-make-aws-ecs-services-communicate-over-service-discovery

Comment: @MarkB my ecs services have been merged into one service. and only my service X sees another service, I set up a map where I wrote ServiceConfigurations__Services__1__Name=service_name
ServiceConfigurations__Services__1__BaseUri=http://localhost:5003